# How to SELECT a record, UPDATE it and be sure it hasn't been updated in the mean?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to do something like that:

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE option='1' ORDER BY time LIMIT 1
```

then with the id in $id

```
UPDATE table SET used='1' WHERE id='$id'
```

The problem is that this way another user can update the same record in the same time.
Is there a way to do that in one only operation ?

Thanks

Comment: Google the combination of: `php+mysql+transaction`

Comment: [Transactions are your friend.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html)

Comment: Transactions are not your friend (in this instance). This is either a trivial case (see Naveen's answer) or a *locking* problem (see CodeAngry's answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE table SET used='1' 
  WHERE id=
    (SELECT id FROM
         (SELECT id FROM table 
          WHERE option='1'
          ORDER BY time 
          LIMIT 1)    AS tmptable
    )
```

Comment: @Greg2fs Please mark as answer, helpful to others find answer easily. Thanks :)

Comment: In fact it doesn't work as is, this is how it can work: 

    UPDATE table SET used='1' 
    WHERE id=
    (SELECT id FROM 
    (SELECT id FROM table 
    WHERE option='1'
    ORDER BY time 
    LIMIT 1) as tmptable
    )

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a three step query if you have concurrent access to the same row by different users.

1. **First** query has to **reserve the row for a certain user** (*using a dedicated field*).
2. **Second** query has to **check if the row reservation is for that certain user**.
3. **Third** query **updates the row** knowing there's no collision as that user reserved it.

Between step #1 and #2, multiple users can try to grab edit access to the row but in the end only one succeeds. The ones that failed will not reach step #3.

**PS**: *This might be overkill for your needs but it's the best way to ensure multiple users work on tasks (rows) concurrently.*

**PPS**: *Or just combine the queries into a single one as another answer points out. But if your update requires some work done, it's best to decide upfront who will do the work before updating the value.*

Comment: Yes it's a solution I already thought about, but I wanted to know if there had simpler. Thanks

Comment: @Greg2fs If the user (worker) that updates needs to do some work that lasts for a while, then you need to decide upfront who will do it. There' no point in 2-3 workers to pick-up the same task, work for it and then collide when updating the values. So... it all depends on what you do. Simple value update can just go as a transaction. Value update that requires some thinking (work) needs to be reserved first to ensure only one works for that certain task.

Answer (score -1):

You could use: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

mysql_insert_id

Finds the last id updated or set and stores it. We then check to make sure the last id does not exist.

so...

```
//last id being the id of the last query set or updated
$last_id = $mysql->insert_id;

if($last_id != $id) {
//execute code
{
else {

echo "last id already in database!";

}
```

If I misinterpreted the question you should still be able to see how to use that last id to do what you want.

Here is an example of it being used. First we update the table with the form data which created our ID. Then we add the input check boxes array to the last id updated.

```
//define input variables
$lesson_id = $_POST['lesson_id'];
$user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
$instructor_id = $_POST['instructor_id'];
$lesson_comments = $_POST['lesson_comments'];
$lesson_date = date("Y-m-d");
$video_ids = isset($_POST['checkbox']) ? $_POST['checkbox'] : array();  # this is  called a ternary operator

//insert lesson information first
$query ="INSERT INTO swing_viewer_lessons (lesson_id, user_id, instructor_id,      lesson_comments, lesson_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
$stmt->bind_param("iiiss", $lesson_id, $user_id, $instructor_id, $lesson_comments,    $lesson_date);
$stmt->execute();
//printf($stmt->error);
echo "successful";
//echo "$last_id";
}

//insert lesson information
if (is_array($video_ids) && count($video_ids) > 0)
{
foreach($video_ids as $list);   
}   

// Make it into a comma separated list
$rec_ids = implode(',', $video_ids);    

//get last inserted id from above
$last_id= $mysqli->insert_id;

//finally query and update lesson information based on the last id added from above
$query ="UPDATE swing_viewer_lessons SET video_ids=? WHERE id=?";
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
$stmt->bind_param("si", $rec_ids, $last_id);
$stmt->execute();
}
```

Hopefully this helps you or anyone else for that matter, as at one point I was pulling hair at this.

Comment: You seem to be solving for the opposite case (`update` *then* `select`)

Comment: Did you not read what I wrote? It is an example of work which you could use to reference. I won't do work for you. I will help you. Is that not the motto around here? Down vote for what?

Comment: I didn't ask the question.

Comment: The OP asks how to prevent concurrent updates to the same existing record. Your answer describes how to get the id of a newly inserted record. I've downvoted the answer because it is not related to the question.

Comment: exactly.. it holds the ID for the statement being processed. No one else has access to it as it is the last ID updated/selected/set from the query before hand. It does answer the question. It also gives an example of it being used in the wild. The example may not be using his statement but someone like yourself or anyone else should see it if you can actually code.

Comment: Rather than attempting to insult me, please try to understand what the original question *actually asks*. The question assumes two (or more) concurrent processes attempting to act on a record *with the same ID*. You say "no one else has access to it" - not only is this is false in your case - it's the *premise of the question*. This is an example of a locking problem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(database)) and your answer does nothing to address the locking problem. See the upvoted answers for actual solutions.